# Strange issue with normals of specific faces in mesh

Tags: normals

I'm having a strange issue with my normals:

[image]

The normal map (baked off of a photogrammetrical mesh) has no issues.

Recalculating normals doesn't help, nor does flipping the specific faces, except that the diagonal distribution of the pink and magenta, as seen in the selected face, is somewhat flipped, like so:

[image] [image]

There are seemingly no issues with the mesh, either, and it has no modifiers. I tried triangulating the faces, but the problem remains. I'm using Eevee, but in Cycles the effect is similar to triangulating the faces (which is something that rendering engine might be doing internally?).

**Does anyone have any idea about what could be causing this?**

Comment: Have you thought about if that may be an UV problem? Maybe they are too close or overlapping on your normal map.

Comment: @taiyo I ..hadn't. Turns out they are indeed overlapping (edit: they are actually crossed, or twisted, overlapping themselves), as I projected the UV map from view. I'll remap and rebake, thank you!